# How much technical skills are needed for CEO?

Tags: management, startup, leadership

Let's consider a genius new graduated software engineer who knows several technologies like Angular/React/ReactNative/NodeJS/MongoDB/PostgreSQL/etc and starts and leads a new startup/company and they will lunch a nice product at the market and get success.

As the company becomes larger and they will hire more developers/other staffs, our founder will have more CEO responsibilities and have no time to lead the developer, so hires a CTO instead. After years the founders tech knowledges expires and new technologies will come that he won't have any knowledge about them. So, what will happen?

I like to know should a founder/CEO keep studying new technologies in detail like a senior developer or it's possible to have a CEO that he doesn't know anything about new technologies?

What is the best solution for this?

> EDIT: My consideration was about now biggest tech companies like
>   Microsoft/Apple/Facebook/etc those started with a genius man in a
>   garage! I want to know when they stopped coding and studying new
>   technologies if it even happend?

Comment: That question is a bit broad. The answer depends on several factors (how big has the company become, how many different technologies are used, how much CEO-work is actually needed, how fast is the CEO at learning new tech stuff, how involved is he with the ongoing development process ...).

Comment: @d_hippo: I considered big companies like apple/microsoft/facebook/etc that started from zero to beome a hero :)

Comment: This is going to depend on a lot of things from the companies size, growth speed, industry, culture and many other things. Having a highly skilled ceo may be critical for some but unneeded or potentially harmful for others

Comment: Why do I get down votes?

Comment: Actually, a lot of founders are awful CEOs.  Many end up being fired by the board.  At some point you need to transition away from iterating and perfecting technology to marketing and monetizing it.  A lot of founders cannot make that transition.  Maybe they are too emotionally invested in the product, maybe the "business side" doesn't interest them, maybe [insert reason].  Point is, you need the right person at the top and often time the person who was right to start and develop tech is not right to expand and monetize.

Comment: CEO (full time) is not a techie role, it's a business role.

Answer (score 2):

First: Not all tech companies are website/apps/webservice developers. Those are the companies that you've mentioned that might be founded by "a genius guy" in a garage.

In some fields, like mechanical or chemical engineering, or maybe medic equipment, experience still counts a lot and is not outdated so easily. In these fields, a retired university professor is more likely to be a founder than a wiz kid.

Then there is the problem with scale. If there are 5 people in the company, I expect the CEO to be a hand-on person. If the technical team is comprised of 5 people but there are 20+ factory floor/sales employees, I'd expect the CTO to manage the bulk of people and bureaucracy while the CEO-founder ir still hands-on with the core activity of the business.

The thing happens when there is a stratification of teams, where at some point, the tech team needs to be managed by a tech lead, and tech leads need to be managed by a software architect. In other fields, a subsystem team has its own product owner, which respond to a systems architect which also leads an integration team, and the company's technical assets are managed by an engineering director under a VP. This is what creates a big distance from the founder and the hands-on activity.

But notice that if we pick 1:5 as the healthy manager-to-managed people ratio, then 3 layers of management would imply 125 employees, all of which are working with technical stuff. This is when I believe a CEO/founder should either assume a fully executive role or place someone else as CEO while maintaining a mixed role such as when Bill Gates became "Chief Software Architect".

In extreme examples, if a company has 5 people, I'd like the CEO to be very knowledgeable both technically and in the product inner details. If a company has a thousand employees and is publicly traded, maybe it's best if the CEO was a former CEO in a different company, even if he knows nothing about the technology (John Snow style).

Investors coming along are a whole different matter. They'll normally push back the wiz-kid for the top-spot and get some white-headed war hero to manage their precious equity.

Also note

Answer (score -1):

Hahahhahahahahahah.

CEO stands for "cash-extraction-officer". You're effectively a glorified sales person, who has to pull cash from VCs, customers, bankers, pets, anyone and everyone.

None of that overlaps with being a software engineer. As a CEO you'll come to hate engineers, with their determination that "the code needs refactoring" - you cannot sell refactored code for more.

Coding also takes time and distracts you from extracting cash. The cash you extract can be used to hire some programmer though, with a bit left over, so your time is better spent extracting cash than even worrying about technical details.

The only time you'll be involved, as a CEO, in technical details would be "should we use AWS or Azure", and only then because it's the sheer cost of the thing.

Comment: Extracting that cash is what pays for engineers, marketing, and everything else.  You gotta extract that cash!!